# Format date function - Customizing output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, format

I am new on PHP and I am trying to retrieve date from my database and format it from this: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to this format: dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss. My first thought was to convert the format before store in the server, but I have read that it is a bad practice, so I am trying to do it when outputting the data.

The point is, it is not working, when I use Format function it changes the format, but in a wrong way.

In this example I am using 'MM/dd/yyyy' format string, but I have already tryied with different formats and the output is always the same.

The table column is in datetime format, but I have experimented with text and varchar formats, in the first case the output is the same as the one from datetime format and in the second case I just receive the first four numbers.

One more thing, I am using PDO.

This is my query:

```
   public function funcaoTesteGetValues() {

        $query = "SELECT teste_data,FORMAT(teste_data,'MM/dd/yyyy') AS 'nova_data' FROM teste";

        $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);  

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    }
```

Here goes the output:

[teste_data] => 2015-12-04 04:04:00 => database format (datetime)

[nova_data] => 20,151,204,040,400 => output formatted

What I need:

04-12-2015 04:04:00[image]

Comment: Why not return it as a date and format it in PHP?

Comment: If it is possible it would solve my problem. But I didn't find this possibilite in my research. How would that work? I thought in formating it with javascript, but it is my last option.

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQL Server? The output looks more like the MySQL FORMAT() output than SQL Server's.

Comment: @aynber I am new on PHP as I said, but I believe I am. With second item (nova_data) I am using FORMAT function. But I am not sure if it is really your question.

Comment: @Berg_Durden No, my question is related to the database server you're using. You mention SQL Server in the title, but the output you're getting doesn't look like what would be expected.

Comment: @aynber I didn't know the difference, I just corrected the title. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Cid  I am using MySql. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: okay, no worries. Make sure to use proper tags when having a question about SQL. Answers can often be differents between between differents systems (MySQL, SQL Server, pgSQL...)

Comment: While a lot of database systems use a lot of the same syntax, each one has it's own functions and quirks. This is why making sure you specify the correct DBMS is crucial, especially when using the built-in functions.

Comment: @Cid. Yes, I'll do that. It was a lack of knowledge, I really thought that it was the same thing. I just found out the difference now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @aynber thanks for pointing out that. It will make my future researches much easier.

Comment: @Berg_Durden that's when one does mistakes that one learns :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) is for numbers rounded to a certain number of decimal places. You want [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) with the correct format identifiers

```
DATE_FORMAT(teste_data,'%m/%d/%Y') AS 'nova_data'
```

*Note* This is only if your database server is MySQL.

Comment: It worked great. Thank you very much. I can't believe it is so simple. I spent hours and more hours trying to solve that and now (thanks to both of you), I just find that I was looking for the wrong information. Thanks again.